# SSRS Tablix Properties - Filter By In/Not In Multiple Items

Tags: filter, reporting-services, filtering, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

We have two tables in our report and the logic should be as follows:

[image]

if we click on the table to see the filter it looks as follows
the expression reads:  `=mid(Fields!perf_code.Value,3,1)` 
where the third character in our perf code is G then return that row here.
what we need to do is say where the third character in our perf code is in G or V then return the rows.

[image]

I've tried to make it look like this
[image]
and like this
[image]
and like this
[image]

none of it seems to be working.
I don't know how to say if the perf code (3 character) is in multiple values in our case G or V then return the row. I have a second output set/tablix where the value should be not <> or not in and that too isn't working.

In short, we need to return all the rows where the 3 character equals multiple possible things, I need to be able to identify all of those values.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the filter expression to

```
= (MID(Fields!perf_code.Value,3,1) = "G" OR MID(Fields!perf_code.Value,3,1) = "V")
```

Then set the Operator to `=`

And finally set the filter expression to value to `=True`. You need to click the `[fx]` button

[image]

And then set the expression to `=True`

[image]

Comment: it didn't work, generated an error "The processing of FilterExpression for the tablix 'table3' cannot be performed. Cannot compare data of types System.Boolean and System.String. Please check the data type returned by the FilterExpression. (rsComparisonTypeError)"

Comment: Let me see if I can reproduce it on my test server and I'll update or delete the answer. Did you type "True" in quotes or not?

Comment: I've edited the answer and tested. It works as expected.

Comment: sorry for the delay - its still providing an error cannot compare data of types system.boolean and system.string please check filter expression

Comment: Can you edit your question and show exactly what you are typing in both the filter expression and the value expression. I set up a report and tested by apply the filters on the tablix and it worked fine so there must be something we're overlooking.

Comment: Shouldn't the type be Boolean instead of Text? I've had issues with Booleans not working correctly before and usually use and IIF to change to 1/0.

Comment: I'll check my test report. I don't remember changing it and it definitely worked but that's a good point.

Comment: I've just looked at the test report and it was set to Text, changed to Boolean out of curiosity and it still worked. So I'll wait for @YelizavetaYR to edit the question and go from there.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I was able to get it working using your code. The issue was that the type of element we had set up was set to text and we were evaluating it a a bool. Once i changed that it seemed to work. Thank you.